# javascript - function call in conditional not working

Tags: javascript, object, methods, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, and trying to build a Snake style game.  I have a conditional statement inside an interval update function checking which direction the snake is moving, which calls movement methods in the Snake object to keep it going. Originally, I had this conditional directly in the update function, which worked as intended - the snake kept moving until it hit a wall, where it would stop and wait for different direction input, which it would accept and keep going in a different direction.

It looked like this:

```
//before, with the checks being done in GamePlay.update()
var Snake = (() => {
    let x = 10 * GameBoard.unit;
    let y = 10 * GameBoard.unit;
    let dir = "r";

    let body = [];
    body.unshift({x, y});

    const moveRight = () => {
        x = body[0].x + GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveLeft = () => {
        x = body[0].x - GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveUp = () => {
        y = body[0].y - GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveDown = () => {
        y = body[0].y + GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    return {body, dir, moveLeft, moveRight, moveDown, moveUp};
})();

//inside IIFE called GamePlay
const update = () => {

        if (Snake.dir == "l" && Snake.body[0].x >= GameBoard.LEFT_WALL){
            Snake.moveLeft();
        }
        else if (Snake.dir == "u" && Snake.body[0].y >= GameBoard.TOP_WALL){
            Snake.moveUp();
        }
        else if (Snake.dir == "r" && Snake.body[0].x <= GameBoard.RIGHT_WALL){
            Snake.moveRight();
        }
        else if (Snake.dir == "d" && Snake.body[0].y <= GameBoard.BOTTOM_WALL){
            Snake.moveDown();
        }

    }
```

In the interest of organizing the code into its appropriate objects, I tried to move the conditional movement into the Snake object, placing it into a method called *movement()*, which would be called from the *update()* function, like so:

```
//after, update conditionals moved from GamePlay.update() to Snake.movement()

var Snake = (() => {
    let x = 10 * GameBoard.unit;
    let y = 10 * GameBoard.unit;
    let dir = "r";

    let body = [];
    body.unshift({x, y});

    const moveRight = () => {
        console.log("in moveRight");
        x = body[0].x + GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveLeft = () => {
        x = body[0].x - GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveUp = () => {
        y = body[0].y - GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const moveDown = () => {
        y = body[0].y + GameBoard.unit;
        body.unshift({x, y});
        body.pop();
    }

    const movement = () => {
        console.log("called");
        if (dir == "l" && body[0].x >= GameBoard.LEFT_WALL){
            console.log("in l");
            moveLeft();
        }
        else if (dir == "u" && body[0].y >= GameBoard.TOP_WALL){
            console.log("in u");
            moveUp();
        }
        else if (dir == "r" && body[0].x <= GameBoard.RIGHT_WALL){
            console.log("in r");
            moveRight();
        }
        else if (dir == "d" && body[0].y <= GameBoard.BOTTOM_WALL){
            console.log("in d");
            moveDown();
        }
    }

    const alive = () => {
        return true;
    }

    return {body, dir, movement};
})();


// ... in GamePlay
    const update = () => {

        Snake.movement();

    }
```

This, however, caused the movement to stop functioning after the Snake ran into the right wall (its initial movement on startup is rightward). Before hitting the wall, the *console.log("called")* and *console.log("in r")* are output as expected, but after hitting the wall only the "called" log continues, while "in r" stops, which would make sense if *body[0].x* is greater than *GameBoard.RIGHT_WALL*.  The snake then stops taking any input, and does not move up or downwards, which should not be affected by *body[0].x* being too large.

My confusion comes from the fact that the behaviors different in the two cases, when its the same conditional code, just refactored into an object method, and why the movement would stop accepting directional input when it continues to do so when outside the object.

Comment: Its a new shorthand, added in 2015 apparently, in which object definition can be condensed if the variables have the same name as the object properties. It runs as expected whenever I've used it, ever since discovering under the section Factory Function Introduction > Object Shorthand, https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/javascript/lessons/factory-functions-and-the-module-pattern

Comment: So it is - thanks :)